# WooCommerce cart quantity won't change after cart update

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product-quantity

I use the following snippet to change WooCommerce add to cart quantity rules.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'custom_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 );

function custom_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ) {
$custom_qty_product_ids = array(27345, 27346);
if (!in_array($product->get_id(), $custom_qty_product_ids)) {
    $args['input_value']    = 25;

$args['max_value']  = 500;
$args['min_value']  = 25;
$args['step']       = 25;
} else {
    if (in_array($product->get_id(), $custom_qty_product_ids)){
        $args['input_value']    = 26;

$args['max_value']  = 260;
$args['min_value']  = 26;
$args['step']     = 26;
    }
}
return $args;
}
```

It works on my product page, but the cart quantity won't change after the cart update, here is the screenshot example.

[wc-cart-example-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMX28.png)

The following snippet([original code snippet](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/adjust-the-quantity-input-values/)) works perfectly but I want to apply another rule to product 27345, 27346.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'c_qty_input_args', 10, 2);

function c_qty_input_args($args, $product) {
if(is_singular('product')) {
    $args['input_value'] = 25;
}
    $args['max_value']  = 500;
    $args['min_value']  = 25;
    $args['step']       = 25;

return $args;
}
```

How can I change the snippet and resolve the issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it work everywhere with different settings based on specific products, try the following instead:

```
// General quantity settings
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'custom_quantity_input_args', 10, 2 );
function custom_quantity_input_args( $args, $product ){
    $product_ids = array(27345, 27346);
    $condition   = in_array( $product->get_id(), $product_ids );

    if( ! is_cart() ) {
        $args['input_value'] = $condition ? 25 : 26; // Starting value
    }

    $args['min_value'] = $condition ? 25 : 26; // Minimum value
    $args['max_value'] = $condition ? 500 : 260; // Maximum value
    $args['step']      = $condition ? 25 : 26; // Step value

    return $args;
}

// For Ajax add to cart button (define the min and max value)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_args', 'custom_loop_add_to_cart_quantity_arg', 10, 2 );
function custom_loop_add_to_cart_quantity_arg( $args, $product ) {
    $product_ids = array(27345, 27346);
    $condition   = in_array( $product->get_id(), $product_ids );
    
    $args['quantity'] = $condition ? 25 : 26; // Min value

    return $args;
}

// For product variations (define the min value)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'custom_available_variation_min_qty', 10, 3);
function custom_available_variation_min_qty( $data, $product, $variation ) {
    $product_ids = array(27345, 27346);
    $condition   = in_array( $product->get_id(), $product_ids );
    
    $args['min_qty'] = $condition ? 25 : 26; // Min value
    $args['max_qty'] = $condition ? 500 : 260; // Max value

    return $data;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: I have tested and everything works correctly, perfect solution!!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I have a variable product with id 27525 and many variations, and I want to apply another rule to this product, min qty 1, max qty 24, step 1. I tried to change your code but it won't work, is there a solution for this?

Comment: @user14847965 If you have another question, please ask a new detailed question, thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I post another question here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66361485/how-to-change-woocommerce-variable-product-quantity-rule), hope you can provide some help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use action "woocommerce_update_cart_action_cart_updated" and disbale or remove or replace Quantity section with readonly text.

```
add_action('woocommerce_update_cart_action_cart_updated','action_cart_updated_quantity', 20, 1 );
function action_cart_updated_quantity( $cart_updated_quantity ){

    // apply action with Your Quantity after updating cart.
 }
```